# How can I access an UIButton in the ViewController Class from a function parameter

Tags: swift, function, parameters, viewcontroller, iboutlet

How Can i access an IBOutlet UIButton from a function with 2 param

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnMaxAloud: UIButton!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 
 
   btnMaxAloud.tintColor = UIColor.white

   changeIconColor(btnMaxAloud , red) // this is gets the error has no member 
     
 }

 func changeIconColor(_ uIButtonName:String , _ color:String){
     if varName {
         self.uIButtonName.tintColor = UIColor.color
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong, specifically the argument types for `changeIconColor`. For example this should work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMaxAloud: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        btnMaxAloud.tintColor = UIColor.white
        changeIconColor(btnMaxAloud, UIColor.red)
    }

    func changeIconColor(_ button: UIButton, _ color: UIColor)
    {
        button.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

The function `changeIconColor()` now takes a `UIButton` and `UIColor` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
func changeIconColor(uIButtonName: UIButton, color: UIColor) {
    uIButtonName.tintColor = color
}
```

now in viewDidLoad

```
changeIconColor(uIButtonName: btnMaxAloud, color: .red)
```